# How to remove the "Be the first of your friends to like this" part of the standard iframe Facebook Like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I'm using the standard Facebook Like button (iframe, not fbml). Is there a way to only display the like button, not the 'Be the first of your friends to like this' part?

Answer (score 12):

This is currently not configurable. If you use the `button_count` layout, then you won't see that text.

Answer (score 3):

As of today's date, in the Like Box code, instead of `layout=standard` use `layout=button_count` and that will show the count bubble & remove that text.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this using CSS. Place the like button inside a div. Give the div containing the like button some width. Then set overflow to hidden. Should work!

Comment: This does work, but prevents the 'Post to Wall' box from appearing! So you're really limiting the functionality with this method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just have "x people like this" then:

```
.fb-like { overflow: hidden; width: 171px; }
```

If you want to have just the number of people that like it in a box then with the [Like Button Generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) select `button_count` from the **Layout Style** drop down.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest way is to resize the generated iframe with CSS to 54px width (small button). Unfortunately, the iframe doesn't has a class or ID, but you can match it by src attribute:

```
iframe[src*="://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?"]
```

Of course matching it with a descendant selector is easier.

Comment: The src selector won't work in all browsers. Better to wrap it in a container element.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code of this WordPress plugin should help you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-fan-box-cache/

It caches facebook fanbox and then outputs it without iframe. In that way you can remove any part of the box you like.

Answer (score -3):

If you use components K2. You fix in Items K2

Head name "Social Sharing"