# Why is the facebook "like" button showing "Be the first of your friends to like this"

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I am linking to a page that has 100 likes already.  I just started testing it and its now showing:

```
 Be the first of your friends to like this
```

instead of:

```
100 people like this
```

does anyone know why facebook would show that message above versus showing the number of likes the page have?  Is that configurable or a bug ?

Comment: What code are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that shows when a user who has not liked the page and has no friends who have liked it is logged in. According to this question ([How to remove the "Be the first of your friends to like this" part of the standard iframe Facebook Like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193749/how-to-remove-the-be-the-first-of-your-friends-to-like-this-part-of-the-standa)), this is not configurable.

Comment: turned out i got the URL wrong . . so it was just a typo (and couldn't find the likes)

Answer (score 0):

please check your URL and put this in body tag

```
<!--FB SDK-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   (function (d, s, id)
   {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!--FB SDK-->
```